# Adding a collaborator to my free GitHub account?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I created a GitHub account, and I want to give someone write access so he can push just like me, there is a way to add a collaborator with a free plan? If not, what can I do? (besides buying a paid account, which I'll do in the future)

Comment: With a free account you can only have public repos ;)

Comment: @klaustopher, Is there any way to purchase just one private repo? Or is the only way to pay a monthly fee perpetually?

Comment: @Pacerier No, this is not possible. You pay 7$ a month and get unlimited private repos

Comment: As of January 2019, free users can have unlimited private repos.

Comment: @Thomas yes but only 3 collaborators in a free account.

Comment: With student account, you can have any number of people in private repos

Answer (score 93, accepted):

## Clear Instructions On How to Add A Collaborator - 2020 Update

Pictures are worth a thousand words. Let's put that to the test:

#### Picture Instructions (Click to Zoom in):

[image: Picture Instructions]

.......and videos/gifs are worth another thousand more:

#### Gif Instructions (Click to Zoom in):

Hopefully the pictures/gif make it easier for you to configure this!

[image]

Answer (score 124):

Go to `Manage Access` page under settings (https://github.com/user/repo/settings/access) and add the collaborators as needed.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: All answers are correct, Ill take as correct the first one :p

Comment: The URL is the same, but now (2014) is only a icon and the name is "settings".

Comment: Dead link in the post

Comment: Your link is not working. Please check and refactor it. Thanks @MonaJalal

Comment: It's 2020, there is no more **Collaborators**, it is now **Manage access**.

Comment: Updated for 2020

Answer (score 53):

It is pretty easy to add a collaborator to a free plan.

1. Navigate to the repository on Github you wish to share with your collaborator.
2. Click on the "Settings" tab on the right side of the menu at the top of the screen.
3. On the new page, click the "Collaborators" menu item on the left side of the page.
4. Start typing the new collaborator's GitHub username into the text box.
5. Select the GitHub user from the list that appears below the text box.
6. Click the "Add" button.

The added user should now be able to push to your repository on GitHub.

Comment: I have another question here, since we have set private and public keys to authenticate the user how can a collaborator be able to push to the repository unless his public key is saved in my account? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user525146 The user being added to the repository has to add one or more public keys to their account.  When adding the user to your repository, Github automatically adds the user's public keys to your repository and updates the keys if the user updates their keys.

Comment: It's 2020, there is no more **Collaborators**, it is now **Manage access**.

Answer (score 10):

In the repository, click `Admin`, then go to the `Collaborators` tab.

Answer (score 7):

FYI for future readers. The instructions above are outdated, in particular step 2:
2. Click on **Settings** button

Comment: What are the up-to-date instructions?

Comment: The answer by @DavidMSyzdek appears to be current.

Comment: The [answer by @Suragch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587142/2745495) is now the current.

Answer (score 6):

Yes the set of instructions above are outdated. For the new GitHub the Settings button must be clicked.

Also the person you try to add as a collaborator must have an existing GitHub account. In other words he should have signed up on GitHub first because it is not possible to send collaboration requests merely by typing in the email address of the collaborator.

Answer (score 6):

project link:

```
https://github.com/your_username/you_repo_name/settings
```

you will get a page like this, go to Collaborator and add collaborator [image: Check setting tab]

Comment: It's 2020, there is no more **Collaborators**, it is now **Manage access**.

Answer (score 4):

## 2020 update

It's called **Manage access** now.

Go to your private repo, click the **Settings** tab, and choose **Manage access** from the menu on the left. You are allowed up to three collaborators with the free plan.

**Note:** If the account is an individual account you can still add collaborators that can do a variety of tasks, but a collaborator can't (as far as I know) sign the app in Xcode and submit it to the app store. You need an organization account for that kind of collaborator.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that Github now allows an **unlimited number of collaborators** even on a free account. See https://github.com/pricing.

Answer (score 1):

### 2022 update

Now it's **Collaborators** under *Access* tab.

[image]

**Side Note:** Now If you're using GitHub Free, you can add unlimited collaborators on public and private repositories.

Comment: Well, a free account does not allow collaborators to add files using the web console. I am not sure why this is the case.