# github adding new user to the project

Tags: version-control, github

I am new to github and was wondering how do I do the following tasks.I have setup the Egit in my eclipse loaded the keys and I have the start and upload the project and everything is working. Now here are few things that I need to do and help would be appreciated. I am using a free github account

How do I allow users to work on my project or give them access to my code for checkout and checkin and merge etc. How do I create a release when the project is in a good condition and how do I revert back to the previous release?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a collaborator to my free GitHub account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920320/adding-a-collaborator-to-my-free-github-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without repeating the answers from "[Adding a collaborator to my free GitHub account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920320/adding-a-collaborator-to-my-free-github-account)", I can add that:

- preparing a new release is simply about making a tag (menu Team / Tag) on your local repo through EGit, and then pushing that tag, which isn't *completely* natural with EGit, as shown by [bug 341032](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341032):

> It should contain `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` if you want to push all your locally
>   existing tags.
>   If you only want to push one single tag you need instead
>   `refs/tags/mysingletag:refs/tags/mysingletag`.
>
> In EGit you may do that by running
>
> - `Team > Remote > Push`...
> - choose the right remote URL
> - click "Next"
> - click "Add all tags spec" or enter a custom refspec
> - click "Finish"

- reverting to a previous release is jsut a matter of creating a new branch from a previous tag: See Egit manual, "[From the team menu on a project node, based on a branch, a tag or a Reference:](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#From_the_team_menu_on_a_project_node.2C_based_on_a_branch.2C_a_tag_or_a_Reference:) ".