# How to create a collaborative repository on Github?

Tags: git, github

Hi i want to develop an application using github for collaborative development.

I have created an extra branch on the repository called "Tests" .

So my collaborators must execute

```
git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

to clone the repository

And what we must to do next?

i have read some tutorials using

```
git branch Tests
git checkout Tests
```

but i can´t push to the repository..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a collaborator to my free GitHub account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920320/adding-a-collaborator-to-my-free-github-account) ... [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=github+add+collaborator) gives quite some results...

Comment: Did you follow the tutorials for setting up your repo with your ssh keys?

Answer (score -1):

GitHub Help has some pretty good details on the different ways to collaborate, through pull requests, or direct commits: http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/

If that doesn't answer your question you will need to be more specific about the error you are receiving.