# How can I give access to a private GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I have a private git repository and I would like to extend its access to a member of my team. Will I be able to do it through the Github website? I have the username of my member.

I have tried to do this by going through the admin page of the repository but there isn't such an option as I am not the owner.

Answer (score 94):

If you are the owner it is simple:

- Go to your repo and click the `Settings` button.
- In the left menu click `Collaborators`
- Then Add their name.

Then collaborator should visit this example repo link https://github.com/user/repo/invitations

Source: [Github Docs](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator).

Comment: this did not work.  it complains about a public key when they try and clone the repo.

Comment: I think, it's Settings button on the right side in your repo as I can't see Admin button for my case.

Comment: Since the interface overhaul mid 2013 it is called Settings.

Comment: This also gives them write access. If you want to give read-only access, you should use an organisation.

Comment: This did not work for me. I added a user for a private repo (as a collaborator) but they can't pull from it..

Comment: It's called [manage access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587142/3681880) now.

Comment: What if you aren't the owner? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 25):

It is a simple 3 Step Process : 
1) Go to your private repo and click on ***settings***

2) To the left of the screen click on ***Manage access*** 

3) Then Click on ***Invite Collaborator***

Comment: The year 2020 answer.

Comment: collaborator gets 404 because it's private currently.

Comment: For private repos, can we give admin access to someone instead of a collaborator role? I could see only the collaborator option only.

Comment: There is no settings on my private repo.

Answer (score 16):

It is a **simple 3 Step** Process :

1. Go to your private repo and click on `settings`
2. To the left of the screen click on `Manage access`
3. Then Click on `Invite Collaborator`

> The invited user needs to be logged in to Github before clicking the invitation link in their email or they'll get a `404` error.

Heres a screenshot of how to do it:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Two steps:**
 1. Login and click "Invite someone" in the right column under "People". Enter and select persons github id.
 2. It will then give you the option to "Invite Username to some teams" at which point you simply check off which teams you want to add them to then click "Send Invitation"

**Alternatively:**
 1. Get the persons github id (not their email)
 2. Navigate to the repository you would like to add the user to
 3. Click "Settings" in the right column (not the gearbox settings along the top)
 4. Click Collaborators long the left column
 5. Select the repository name
 6. Where it reads "Invite or add users to team" add the persons github id
 7. An invitation will then be e-mailed.

Please let me know how this worked for you!

Answer (score 4):

It is a simple 3 Step Process :

1. Go to your private repo and click on settings
2. To the left of the screen click on Manage access
3. Then Click on Invite Collaborator

This, but also - the invited user needs to be logged in to Github before clicking the invitation link in their email or they'll get a 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

It´s possible via [Github Organizations](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations). You have to create a new account.

https://github.com/organizations/new

Answer (score 1):

It's working in 2021,

Though the Repo has to be made private first then the click on
`settings => Manage access => Invite Collaborator`

The user who gets the repo access has to navigate to the repo and can make changes to the main branch.

Answer (score -2):

Your team members must be accessing the repository using SSH & for that they have to have their ssh key mapped with github account. This will work if they map their ssh key with github account and also the repository has public rights, which they want to access.

Comment: You shouldn't write this like its the only way to do this, Although this can be achieved its cumbersome at best at the alternatives are easier and fast, offer both if you want to provide a thorough solution