# How do I track a branch from a private forked repo of another user in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

> I and my friend have forked a private repo of another user with our respective user IDs. The forked repo is showing as private in both our accounts. I have done some changes in some branches and pushed it in my repo. I didn't do any Pull request. How can my friend track that branch from his repo?

He has added my repo as remote. But when he tries to fetch using

```
git fetch myRepo
```

He is getting the following error

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myRepo/repo-name.git/' not found
```

I have tried addind my friend as a collaborator in my repo, but this is how the collaborator section of my repo looks like;

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I give access to a private GitHub repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886174/how-can-i-give-access-to-a-private-github-repository)

Comment: @Sjoerd No, it's not a possible duplicate. Read the example I have given. I can access the private repo. I want to give access to a forked private repo to another user and I can't add that user as a collaborator, that is why I have asked this question.

Comment: Isn't this a question best directed to the GitHub administration?

Answer (score 1):

You should add User3 as [a collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/) to the User1 repository.

Comment: The collaborator section doesn't allow me to add user, check my edited question, I have given a screenshot.