# Collaborating with a single private repository on Github

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

I'm working on a small project where about 4-5 of us need to collaborate on some code which we want to keep private. I have unlimited private repos on github, and we don't want to shell out money for a private organization. What are the pros and cons of me sharing my login credentials with them and all of us working simultaneously on the same repo?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cons - your colleagues have your username and password.

Answer (score 2):

> Never Share Your Credentials!!

If you have unlimited private repositories, you can create one private repository for your project and add them as collaborators. Refer to this on how to do it (Same approach for private and public repos)-> [Adding a collaborator to my free GitHub account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920320/adding-a-collaborator-to-my-free-github-account)

This way your files will remain private, every person will use their own accounts for commits, pulls, etc. The one downside will be that you will not have an organization, the repository will be under your username. You can later transfer ownership or migrate it to an organisation when you decide to