# Push remote with ssh key but report error

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I created a private repository with detailed info

```
$ git config --list
user.name=AlphaAlgorithms
user.email=***@live.com
credential.helper=cache
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/AlphaAlgorithms/OrgMode.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Use the https as original style and it works to push remote

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 631 bytes | 631.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/AlphaAlgorithms/OrgMode.git
   d67d7ef..3193d01  master -> master
```

However, if change https to ssh

```
   me@alpha:~/Documents/OrgMode:
    $ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:AlphaAlgorithms/OrgMode.git
    me@alpha:~/Documents/OrgMode:
    $ git push
    ERROR: Repository not found.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

It failed and prompt not correct rights, the ssh key are binded.

```
me@alpha:~/Documents/OrgMode:
$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:Mud1bhP0BuQKJtw4rAvZpCSTMBifE6EUHmC+ppB7zeo /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
4096 SHA256:S/l+QqvaRQpu1cAnvltH78w/bjgxc9xKL4gFzxvpMqI **@live.com (RSA)
```

What's the problem?

Run `git push -v`

```
$ git push -v
Pushing to git@github.com:AlphaAlgorithms/OrgMode.git
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

run `ssh -vv git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [52.74.223.119] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-80573d3e
debug1: no match: babeld-80573d3e
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gaowei/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55b55c6a6a30), agent
debug2: key: igabriel_improve@live.com (0x55b55c6a9be0), agent
debug2: key: /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_xmss ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:Mud1bhP0BuQKJtw4rAvZpCSTMBifE6EUHmC+ppB7zeo /home/gaowei/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:Mud1bhP0BuQKJtw4rAvZpCSTMBifE6EUHmC+ppB7zeo
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([52.74.223.119]:22).
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_CA.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 95
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 7/(95)
Hi KernelWhisper! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 95 to efd 7
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 4288, received 2512 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5821.1, received 3410.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I once used another github account KernelWhiper, and now updated the ssh key and user

```
user.name=AlphaAlgorithms
user.email=igabriel_improve@live.com
credential.helper=cache
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:AlphaAlgorithms/OrgMode.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Thanks. And `ssh -vv git@github.com` shows that you can authenticate with your key? (Yes, two `vv`, it adds verbose detail.)

Comment: Seems so! `Hi KernelWhisper! You've successfully authenticated, but `...

Comment: Are you the owner of the repo? Have you been granted push access as an external contributor? I see the username from ssh is not the namespace of the repo? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920320/adding-a-collaborator-to-my-free-github-account

Comment: Yes, I created it minutes ago `https://github.com/AlphaAlgorithms/OrgMode.git`. @msanford

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+two+accounts